# Excel curve (Showing values at both sides of y-axis)

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I have created a curve in Excel 2013.

At the Y-Axis I am showing some values that show the probability for survival for each 100.000 citizen. Now my problem is, that I want to also show it in percentage, at the right side of the Y-Axis.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Ps. I have added an the curve as an image, so that you can see how it looks at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a [secondary (Y) axis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-combo-chart-with-a-secondary-axis-HA102813789.aspx):

Create a combo chart with a secondary axis

When the numbers in a chart you created vary widely from data series to data series, or when you have mixed types of data (for example, price and volume), you can plot one or more data series on a secondary vertical (value) axis. The scale of the secondary vertical axis shows the values for the associated data series. A secondary axis works well in a chart that shows a combination of column and line charts.

Combo chart with secondary axis

In Microsoft Excel 2013, you can quickly show a chart like the one above by changing your chart to a combo chart.

```
Click anywhere in the chart you want to change to a combo chart to show the Chart Tools.
```

Chart Tools

```
Click Design > Change Chart Type.
```

Type group on the Design tab

```
On the All Charts tab, choose Combo, and then pick the Clustered Column - Line on Secondary Axis chart.
```

Combo chart with secondary axis on All Charts tab

```
Under Choose the chart type and axis for your data series, check the Secondary Axis box for each data series you want to plot on the secondary axis, and then change their chart type to Line.
Make sure that all other data series are shown as Clustered Column.
```

To clarify what is plotted on each of the vertical axes, you can add axis titles.

.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you only need a right axis that shows a percentage scale, with, e.g., the tick mark for 100% at the same level as the tick mark for 100000 on the left axis.
You do not need any additional curves.

Then, you need to:

1. Create some dummy data. You may use two cells, which will give you a series with a single data point. Use 10 (X range) and -1 (Y range). Depending on the options you selected for your y axis, you may have to set the Minimum value fixed at 0 (you can do this now or later).
2. Add it to the plot.
3. Assign it to a secondary y-axis. Right-click on the series, Format Data Series -> Series Options -> Secondary Axis. Or, if you find it difficult to select it this way, select the chart, Go to Format, select the series from the pull-down menu on the top left, and Format Selection.
4. Format the right axis scale to give you a correct matching with the left scale. Right click on the secondary y axis, set the Minimum fixed at 0, the Maximum fixed at 1.2 (to match the figure you posted), and the number format as Percentage. PS: there will be a tick label "120%" on the right axis. That will not look good for what you are plotting. It will be best to set the Maximum of the left axis to 115000 (say), and the right axis to 1.15 then.